# Problema con menu navbar de Boostrap, se abre y selecciona automáticamente

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, navbar

pues estoy tratando de armar un panel de control con una plantilla que compré:
https://www.bootstrapdash.com/demo/star-admin-pro/src/demo_1/index.html

Sin embrago, ese inconveniente ya me pasó con una plantilla gratuita que estaba probando y tenía el mismo funcionamiento. Resulta que el menú detecta automáticamente los enlaces de mi menú lateral y por defaul apertura el menú y los marca en azul (como seleccionándolos). 
Este es el comportamiento y el código actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, si quito el texto "panel" de mis enlaces, todo funciona de maravilla :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, mis urls están estructuradas con el texto "panel" en un inicio. ¿Existe alguna manera para desactivar esta función?

Infinitas gracias de antemano.

PD: Estoy utilizando la plantilla exactamente con los archivos que tiene, no he agregado ni eliminado absolutamente nada. 
https://www.bootstrapdash.com/product/star-admin-pro/#product-demo-section

Comment: ¿A Nadie le ha pasado? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A falta de ayuda tuve que indagar todo el código fuente de la plantilla en unos de sus archivos me encontré esto. Lo comenté y se soluciono.

```
var current = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0].replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
    $('.nav li a', sidebar).each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (current === "") {
        //for root url
        if ($this.attr('href').indexOf("index.html") !== -1) {
          $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().addClass('active');
          if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
          }
        }
      } else {
        //for other url
        if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
          $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().addClass('active');
          if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
          }
          if (current !== "index.html") {
            $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().find(".nav-link").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
            if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
              $(this).closest('.collapse').addClass('show');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```